# Azure Linux Web Apps (Node) Crash with message: " Segmentation fault (core dumped) " and restart

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, web-applications, crash

Two azure webapps that run node js 10.14.1 version on linux started crashing unexpectedly this week (since 27th of January 2021 till today 29 of January 2021). They crash very rarely (just 4 times as far as I can see 2 for the first one and 2 for the second one). The only logged message I get is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and then the app restarts. It seems to be happening randomly but never when the app is iddle, only when it processes some request. Sometimes the app crashes on very light load sometimes on very high load, it's not predictable by anything I can measure or I'm not seeing it at least.

Both these apps run NestJS framework and they are JavaScript backend solutions, they've been running smoothly for 3 years now. I haven't updated or added any new npm packages to them or changed any kind of configuration the past 2 months. Does anyone know how to debug this? I have enabled file system logs for all those apps and all I get from KUDU logs is the message I told you about. Sadly I don't have technical support in my support plan. Also it has happened in the passed that this sort of problems were cause by azure updates, so this is where my mind mostly goes, but never with this error so I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1. Open WebSSH.
2. Use below command to install `segfault-handler`.

   ```
   root@ddc****** :/home# apt-get upgrade
   root@ddc****** :/home# apt-get install build-essential
   root@ddc****** :/home# npm install segfault-handler
   ```
3. Then you can use `segfault-handler`.

[image]

You can read this blog first.

[How to Debug Node.js Segmentation Faults](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-debug-node-segfaults/)

I think you can [Find the culprit](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-debug-node-segfaults/#find-the-culprit) and fix it.

To do this, you can use the `Segfault-Handler` module. Just run `npm install segfault-handler`, and then add the below right at the start of your application code:

```
const SegfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');
SegfaultHandler.registerHandler('crash.log');
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Although writting to a file on azure services is bound to create problems, actually I think it's not even possible since continuous intergration is enabled but I'll see if I can open a local docker and try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sadly I can't install this npm without python on my system and not sure this is possible for when I deploy on azure appservice.

Comment: @Periklis I have updated my answer, it works for me.

Comment: @Periklis Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: yes there's some progress. I think I found a native module that might be causing this. It's the bunyan logger which has a native module dependency called dtrace-provider. So far it seems that this was the problem although no idea why it suddenly started to have a problem after 3 years of working smoothly without any issues. I was able to get in contact with a MS tech support currrently to clarify the issue and I'll get back to this post to update. Tahnk you very much for your input!

Comment: @Periklis Generally speaking, it runs stably for a long time, unless there is an upgrade plan on the azure service that causes the service to be abnormal. This log cannot be queried, and MSFT is needed for assistance. What I give is just the usual ideas of our program developers, using programming methods to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jason Pan's answer I went to the blog post [How to Debug Node Segfaults](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-debug-node-segfaults/) and saw that the possible issue could be a native module. Before this, I did not know about native modules or that they could do any potential damage. I could not install the segfault-handler npm in azure service howerver I did install the [native-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-modules) npm which showed me that bunyan logger (which I'm using as main backend logger in all my linux node servers) had a dependency called dtrace-provider which is a native module. After removing this the problem stopped happening! I still think some azure process changed in the background through, an update or something similar, and all of a sudden this npm started to cause crashes. I'm simply posting this in case it helps anyone debug this without installing the segfault-handler.